# In Vue, when options of select element are not immediately available, initial state differs depending on whether using v-model or value/input bindings

Tags: vue.js, select

See below the two selects, the only difference between them is that the second is using value binding and input event binding. After the options array is populated their values should be the same ('Two') but that's not what I am seeing.

Of course if we change the value with the dropdown then everything works ok. But the initial state differs. I read that v-model is syntactic sugar for v-bind:value and v-on:input, but it seems not to be the case.

In my case I can't use v-model (the value is not directly settable, so I need to use value/input bindings). Any suggestions?

```js
console.clear()

let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    x: 2,
    options: []
  }
})
app.options = [
    { text: 'One', id: 1 },
    { text: 'Two', id: 2 },
    { text: 'Three', id: 3 }
];
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  <select v-model="x">
    <option v-for="o in options" :value="o.id">{{ o.text }}</option>
  </select>
  <span>{{ x }}</span>
  
  <br>
  
  <select :value="x" @input="x = $event.target.value">
    <option v-for="o in options" :value="o.id">{{ o.text }}</option>
  </select>
  <span>{{ x }}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

If you really need it that way you could do workaround with `selected` but update your Vue version to latest because with version you use there will still be problems.

```html
<select :value="x" @input="x = $event.target.value">
  <option v-for="o in options" :value="o.id" :selected="x===o.id">{{ o.text }}</option>
</select>
```

Full example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qxfs9zon/)

Original:

Everything is ok with your bindings. You should get options before creating Vue instance and then drop it in `data`

```js
let options = [
  { text: 'One', id: 1 },
  { text: 'Two', id: 2 },
  { text: 'Three', id: 3 }
]

let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    x: 2,
    options
  }
})
```

Or use regular Vue lifecycle hooks like `created` and get options at that point

```js
let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    x: 2,
    options: []
  },
  created () {
    this.options = [
      { text: 'One', id: 1 },
      { text: 'Two', id: 2 },
      { text: 'Three', id: 3 }
    ]
  }
})
```

Comment: yeah I cant do that. In my real case I get the options using ajax a lot later after I create and mount the component. Also, I would like to find an explanation for the difference in behaviour between the two anyway.

Comment: sorry, I don't know the explanation since I didn't have need to use it that way. And to me it looks like it is not the 'Vue way' of doing things. Why don't you simply use method for ajax and call it on some event? Can you create full example on JSFiddle?

Comment: check updated answer for workaround if you really need it the way you explained

Comment: Yes 'selected' binding works fine. As far as ajax is concerned, the same happens even when triggering it inside an event. I think it has to do something with the v-model implementation in select element. I haven't looked at the code of vue. Anyway thanks.